# AWS Cloudformation | Configure Lambda to Use Latest Version of Code in S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Im using codepipeline, codebuild and cloudformation on AWS.

My flow is:

1. Push a commit to github, this triggers the codepipeline
2. Codebuild uploads (zipped) lambda functions to S3 bucket
3. Cloudformation configure lambda functions

Cloudformation (simplified):

```
CreateDoctorLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: python3.6
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaExecutionRole
          - Arn
      Code:
          S3Bucket: !Ref LambdaFunctionS3Bucket
          S3Key: CreateDoctor.zip
          S3ObjectVersion: Latest <-- This value is invalid
```

**Problem:** When I update the code for lambda functions (this new code is zipped and uploaded to the S3 bucket during codebuild), the change is not deployed to the existing lambda functions.

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html):

> To update a Lambda function whose source code is in an Amazon S3
>   bucket, you must trigger an update by updating the S3Bucket, S3Key, or
>   S3ObjectVersion property. Updating the source code alone doesn't
>   update the function.

**Question:** Is there any way to tell Cloudformation to use the latest version of the code stored in S3? Using `S3ObjectVersion: Latest` will result in an error.

Comment: HI, i am also got struck at same usecase. Did you able to find out the value for `S3ObjectVersion` so that lambda will get latest s3 zip file ?

Comment: @Private Unfortunately not.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. I asked the same in aws forum too, hoping i will get any positive response.

Comment: @Private please consider to share if you find a solution :-)

Comment: Sure. I will share..

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue, can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just an alternative workflow, but maybe it will solve your problem:

1. Instead of saving the artifact with the same name, you must configure CodePipeline or CodeBuild to generate a different name for the artifact based, for example, in the deploy time;
2. At your CloudFormation Action you pass the artifact name as a parameter for the template (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html) and it will redeploy the function based on new code.

Answer (score 1):

S3ObjectVersion could be extracted into `Parameters` section and the latest version could be passed to it dynamically.

Below is `org-babel` version but it can be converted into shell script instead.

```org
#+name: latest-lambda-version
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output :var bucket=artifact-bucket-name
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucket --prefix lambda-function.zip --query 'Versions[?IsLatest].[VersionId]' --output text
#+END_SRC


#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results verbatim silent :var version=latest-lambda-version
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file stack.yml \
                          --stack-name FooStack \
                          --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
                          --parameter-overrides LambdaVersion="${version}" \
                          --no-execute-changeset
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack that works well if you have a lot of lambdas in your CF stack so you want to manually select which lambdas to update from the source, and have lambda code that will work equally well under multiple runtimes. Just change the runtime version in your stack (say from "Runtime: nodejs8.10" to "Runtime: nodejs10.x". CodePipeline/CloudFormation will update just that function.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was also similar but I didn't use aws-cloudformation.
I have configured AWS pipeline to deploy my latest nodeJS code as zip file to S3. Instead of going to AWS Lambda and manually choosing the "upload from Amazon S3 location" option, I needed my lambda function to take the latest code once it is written to S3, so that it will automatically update its function code when you update the zip file in S3 through AWS pipeline.

Solution that worked for me is in this link:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71079021/10049471